# stroke-dasharray in polyline SVG

Tags: svg, polyline

I have a polyline attribute

```
 <polyline points="229.7610294117647,200.44669117647058 
 293.93566176470586,148.9485294117647 325.6268382352941,95.8658088235294 
 374.74816176470586,124.38786764705881 389.00919117647055,218.6691176470588 
 346.22610294117646,305.02757352941177 263.8290441176471,311.3658088235294 
 232.1378676470588,215.5 " id="myCanvas_bg_obj_kpts0_43390" fill="none" 
 stroke-dasharray="5, 5" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.5"></polyline>
```

The problem I am having is the dashed stroke is not showing up.
Could not find any resources on dashed stroke for polyline. What am i missing here or in my resource search. Please help me out on this.

Help much appreciated

Comment: You've not set a stroke e.g. stroke="red"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as advised Robert Longson stroke="red"

[image]

The file is opened in the vector editor [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)

The image shows that the svg figure appears in the visibility zone, it needs to be shifted to the left and up.

This can be done in two ways:

1. add `viewport`,  `viewBox`

and shift the image using the transformation command

`transform="translate(-130 -50)"`

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
 <g transform="translate(-130 -50)">
 <polyline points="229.7610294117647,200.44669117647058 
 293.93566176470586,148.9485294117647 325.6268382352941,95.8658088235294 
 374.74816176470586,124.38786764705881 389.00919117647055,218.6691176470588 
 346.22610294117646,305.02757352941177 263.8290441176471,311.3658088235294 
 232.1378676470588,215.5 " id="myCanvas_bg_obj_kpts0_43390" fill="none" 
 stroke-dasharray="5, 5" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="red"></polyline> 
 </g>
 </svg>
```

2. Instead of the `translate` transformation command, use the attributes `x-min=130`, `y-min=50`

`viewBox="130 50 400 400"`

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="130 50 400 400" >
 
 <polyline points="229.7610294117647,200.44669117647058 
 293.93566176470586,148.9485294117647 325.6268382352941,95.8658088235294 
 374.74816176470586,124.38786764705881 389.00919117647055,218.6691176470588 
 346.22610294117646,305.02757352941177 263.8290441176471,311.3658088235294 
 232.1378676470588,215.5 " id="myCanvas_bg_obj_kpts0_43390" fill="none" 
 stroke-dasharray="5, 5" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="red"></polyline> 
 
 </svg>
```